# await with array foreach containing async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await

In node.js I need to use a `function procesMultipleCandidates ()` which contains Array.foreach which process insert every element into db. but the entire function should return response after completing all insertion operation

**JavaScript Code**

```
async function procesMultipleCandidates (data) {
  let generatedResponse = []
  await data.forEach(async (elem) => {
    try {    
          
           // here candidate data is inserted into  
           let insertResponse = await insertionInCandidate(elem) 
           //and response need to be added into final response array 
           generatedResponse.push(insertResponse)
    } catch (error) {
    console.log('error'+ error);
    }
  })
  console.log('complete all') // gets loged first
  return generatedResponse // return without waiting for process of 
}
```

And as described above last return statement not waiting for the `foreach` execution to complete first.

Comment: Your data.forEach itself blocks the execution until the callback finishes execution. You need not use 'await'  at that point.

Comment: this was helpful for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
async function procesMultipleCandidates (data) {
  let generatedResponse = []
  await Promise.all(data.map(async (elem) => {
    try {
      // here candidate data is inserted into  
      let insertResponse = await insertionInCandidate(elem)  
      // and response need to be added into final response array 
      generatedResponse.push(insertResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error'+ error);
    }
  }))
  console.log('complete all') // gets loged first
  return generatedResponse // return without waiting for process of 
}
```

Or use a [`for/of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop if you don't want the loop run [concurrently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

```js
async function procesMultipleCandidates (data) {
  let generatedResponse = []
  for(let elem of data) {
    try {
      // here candidate data is inserted into  
      let insertResponse = await insertionInCandidate(elem)  
      // and response need to be added into final response array 
      generatedResponse.push(insertResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error'+ error);
    }
  }
  console.log('complete all') // gets loged first
  return generatedResponse // return without waiting for process of 
}
```

Comment: using for/of is way simpler and works perfectly!

Comment: Hello! If it's not too late yet, I have a somewhat similar problem and I asked a question, could you help me please?

Answer (score 9):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` tries to execute sequentially and you may not always get the expected result.

`Array.prototype.map()` is the widely used for creating Promises using data and then resolved using `await Promise.all([])`

> using `.map()` function, all the promises are resolved in parallel and if you happen to call an API you may end up getting `error 429: Too many Requests`

To execute all the promises sequentially, you can use **`for ...of`**.

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (const element of array1) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concern, `for of` works better with asynchrony than `forEach`. Anyway, in this case, if you only care for the aggregated result, I think this could be a solution.

```js
async function procesMultipleCandidates(data) {
  const promises = data.map(insertionInCandidate);
  return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all` instead, which will resolve once all Promises in the array passed to it have resolved. The syntax will probably be simplified if you use and return a plain `Promise` chain rather than `async`/`await`:

```
const procesMultipleCandidates = data => Promise.all(
  data.map(insertionInCandidate)
)
.catch(err => {
  console.log('err: ' + err);
});
```

Note that if there's an error, `procesMultipleCandidates` will currently return a resolved `Promise` rather than rejecting - it might be a better idea to have the *consumer* of `procesMultipleCandidates` handle errors, so that it can handle them appropriately (rather than simply `console.log`ging it).

Comment: in your solution, how the response of each `insertionInCandidate()` can be pushed in one final response array?

Comment: The `.map` is transforming each item in `data` into a `Promise` that resolves to the result of calling `insertionInCandidate` with the item - pass an array of those `Promise`s to `Promise.all`, and the `Promise.all` will resolve to an array of those values. No modifications to the code are needed - it's quite terse and simple.