# How to wait for all processes to end in forEach before returning result (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I want for forEach function to complete before returning results, how do you do this?
The function returns null in all results when I return code because it doesn't wait for forEach to end, so how do i solve this?

```
async function fileResult(fileCard, userId, req, fileTypes) {
  if (req.files && Object.keys(req.files).length) {
    let resultObj = {
      smallResult: null,
      mediumResult: null,
      largeResult: null,
      thumbnailResult: null,
    };

    const result = fileTypes.forEach(async (fileType) => {
      if (req.files[fileType]) {
        try {
          const fileUploadResult = await uploadFile(fileCard, userId, req, fileType);

          if (fileType === 'small') {
            resultObj['smallResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'medium') {
            resultObj['mediumResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'large') {
            resultObj['largeResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'thumbnail') {
            resultObj['thumbnailResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          }

          if (!fileUploadResult.success) {
            console.log(fileUploadResult.error, 500);
            return;
          }

          // console.log(resultObj);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    });

    return resultObj;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738684/await-with-array-foreach-containing-async-await) answer your question?

Comment: i will check it out, that you.

Comment: Thank you it works with Promise.all but i had to change from forEach to map.  And i could use alternative  for/of . Thank you very much

Comment: `.forEach()` should not be used with promises.  You have no flow of control at all with `.forEach()`.  Instead, use `for/of` with `await` to serialize your requests or collect all the promises with `.map()` and use `Promise.all()` to parallelize your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
async function fileResult(fileCard, userId, req, fileTypes) {
  if (req.files && Object.keys(req.files).length) {
    let resultObj = {
      smallResult: null,
      mediumResult: null,
      largeResult: null,
      thumbnailResult: null,
    };

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const result = fileTypes.forEach(async (fileType) => {
      if (req.files[fileType]) {
        try {
          const fileUploadResult = await uploadFile(fileCard, userId, req, fileType);

          if (fileType === 'small') {
            resultObj['smallResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'medium') {
            resultObj['mediumResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'large') {
            resultObj['largeResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          } else if (fileType === 'thumbnail') {
            resultObj['thumbnailResult'] = fileUploadResult;
          }

          if (!fileUploadResult.success) {
            console.log(fileUploadResult.error, 500);
            resolve("done")
            return;
          }

          // console.log(resultObj);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err)
        }
      }
    });
    })

    return resultObj;
  }
}
```

Kindly accept it as answer if it works for you, thanks!

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about using promises , ok i will test it and if it works i will accept it, thank you.