# Loop through parameter values - NodeJS (Puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, for-loop, parameter-passing, puppeteer

I am passing the values I get from `MongoDb` to my parameters in NodeJS Puppeteer with a for-Each loop.

### This is the for-Each loop

```
dataGood = [{title: "username1", password: "password2"},{title: "username1", password: "password2"}]


 await dataGood.forEach(async element => {
        let title = element.title;
        let pass = element.password;
        let tags = element.tags;
        let actions = element.actions;
        
        await ig.initialize();

        await ig.login(title, pass);
  
        await ig.liketagsprocess(tags, actions);
```

This code works fine if there is a single data in the `dataGood`.

But if there are 2 or more values it does not work.

### This is where the data is passed

```
initialize: async() => {
        instagram.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
        });

        instagram.page = await instagram.browser.newPage();
    },

    login: async(username , password) => {

        console.log(username, password)


        await instagram.page.goto(BASE_URL, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});

        await instagram.page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');

        await instagram.page.type('input[name="username"]', username, {delay: 100});

        await instagram.page.type('input[name="password"]', password, {delay: 100});


Console Log : // Suppose usernames are username 1 and Username 2

username1 password1
username2 password2
```

How ever the main problem arises in the puppeteer.

The `for-each` loop of `dataGood`, opens up `2 puppeteer windows`.

Two separate chromium windows open up. and this kind of error happens.

Please refer to these images.

[image: This is the first chromium window where nothing happens]
[image: This is the second chromium window where both parameters gets mixed up]

**These are not the tabs of the same chromium window but entirely different windows**

**How can I loop through the parameters so that they work individually in the respective puppeteer windows.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open all iteratees in the same chromium instance then you should call

```js
await ig.initialize();
```

outside of the loop.

Other than that the `Array.forEach` may not executed the same way as you'd expect it, iterating async functions is tricky. See more on its background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673906/collect-elements-by-class-name-and-then-click-each-one-puppeteer/62612102#62612102).

With a regular `for` loop or with a `for...of` your iteratees will be executed in strict sequence without any side effects:

```js
await ig.initialize();
for (const element of dataGood) {
  let title = element.title
  let pass = element.password
  await ig.login(title, pass)
}
```

If you'd still want to do it in a `forEach` I suggest to refactor your current code to deal with the asyncronous nature of the called functions.