# Puppeteer click also on the second and third items that have the same class

Tags: javascript, node.js, click, puppeteer, mouse

I'm trying to use puppeteer for click on 3 div, but they have the same class.

```js
page.click('.not-selected-1Tb33').then(async () => {
    await page.click('.list-item-MOAq4')
})
```

Puppeteer clicks on the first that it find, but I want to click also on the second and the third that have the same class name.
How I can do? 
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english!

Comment: it always clicks only first element, so try selecting them all, and then loop through each, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673906/collect-elements-by-class-name-and-then-click-each-one-puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for ... of:

```
const buttons = await page.$$(selector)
for (let btn of buttons) {
   await btn.click()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, marked as solution